# Combine multiple DotNet Executables into one executable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution in C# DotNet (VS 2010) that consists of several WinForms GUI executable projects:

- MainMenu.EXE
- Task1.exe
- Task2.exe
- Task3.exe

Each has their own `static void Main()`. Each is invoked by MainMenu.EXE by `Process.Start` when a main menu button is clicked. Is there a way to combine all of these into a single executable?

Comment: Well, a .NET executable is also at the same time a .NET assembly. Thus, if you reference each other .exe file or their projects from the main project, you should be able to call the (static) Main method of each project from your primary project, or call any other public static method and use any public type from those other projects (use different namespaces per project to avoid type name collisions). Technically you will still end up with multiple .exe files, but you don't need to execute them separately through the Process class or similar...

Comment: Note that you need to declare the static Main methods of the other projects as well as the classes containing those Main methods as `public` to make this work...

Comment: There isn't  significant differences between an exe and a dll except the exe has an entry point main (see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/69b30f61-e979-4f31-b090-708d8441965d/how-the-double-click-a-exe-launches-the-application?forum=netfxbcl)  A dll has every method Public so you can call the methods from external applications.  So you can have an entry point in each exe task (like a dll) that is public without main that you can call from other applications.